# How to find an equation for the number of solutions a function have?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If $i, j$ are two integers and a function $f$ can be differentiated $i$ times on a open interval. After the $i^{th}$ derivative it will have $j$ roots.

At least & at most how many roots does the original function $f$ have?

Edited-----------------------------------------

I think at least $0$ root because if

`f(x)=2x^2= -1
i=1(means differentiate the function for i times). 
f^(i)(x) = 0 does not have a root 
Then
F(x) has at least 0 root`

How can I find at most how may roots it will have?

Comment: When you say "solutions", do you mean roots?

Comment: By "solution" do you mean "roots"?  But then, take a function like $f(x)=x^2+1$ and $i=1$.  $f'(x)$ has a root, namely $x=0$.  But $f(x)$ has no roots.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2+1$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, $f'(x)=0$ has 1 solution but $f(x)=0$ has 0 solutions.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean yes roots

Answer (score 1):

Lower bound: As mentioned in the comments, the original function can have as few as zero roots.

---

Upper bound:

If $f'$ has $j$ roots, then $f$ has $j$ critical points so it has $\le j+1$ roots. (Try to draw functions with $i$ critical points and see how often you can cross the $x$-axis.) This can be proved rigorously with the mean value theorem.

Repeating this argument for $f^{(i)}$ having $j$ roots shows that $f$ has at most $j+i$ roots.